# Proving that $f(x)\ge 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> The equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ does not have two distinct real roots, $a\neq0$ and  $a+c>b$. Prove that  $f(x)\ge0,  \forall   x \in R$.

Now, from the question I can interpret two things:

1. $\Delta (= b^2-4ac)\le0$
2. $a>0$

Proving the second point will be a solution to the question (graphically). How do I prove that $a>0$?

Comment: What is $f(-1)$?

Comment: a-b+c @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: $f(-1)=a-b+c >0$

Comment: How does that help @Fred?

Comment: @Abcd It means that the function is positive _somewhere_, and since it doesn't have two distinct roots, it has to keep being positive in at least one direction, either to the left or to the right of $-1$.

Comment: I am not happy with the brief answers given below. They are like comments. No explanation has been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your statement is wrong. Try $b=1$, $c=2$ and $a=0$.

If we are talking  about quadratic equation then $a\neq0$ and

since $a(-1)^2+b(-1)+c>0$, we obtain $a>0$ and $\Delta\leq0$, which says $ax^2+bx+c\geq0$ for all value of $x$.

Comment: a is not zero. Edited.

Comment: How did you obtain $a>0$

Comment: @Abcd Because $f(-1)>0$ and if $a<0$ then $f$ has two distinct roots. Draw it! The graph of $f$ is parabola.

Comment: Your answers are generally *the best*.

Comment: @Abcd Thank you! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is a continuous function with $f(-1)>0$.

Comment: Too brief. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have $(a-c)^2\geq 0$. This gives
$$
a^2 - 2ac + c^2 \geq 0\\
a^2 + c^2 \geq 2ac$$
And since $2ac\geq b^2 - 2ac$, we get
$$
a^2 + c^2 \geq b^2 - 2ac\\
a^2 + 2ac + c^2 \geq b^2\\
(a+c)^2 \geq b^2
$$
Now for the contradiction. Assume $a$ is negative. Then $c$ cannot be positive, because otherwise $b^2 - 4ac$ becomes positive. Therefore $a+c>b$ has negative numbers on either side of the inequality sign, which means that if we square it, we change the direction of the inequality. This yields $(a+c)^2 < b^2$, which contradicts the above inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that if a is negative, than the limit of f(x) as x tends to positive or negative infinity is always negative infinity, and that thus a must be positive to insure condition one. I don't know if you wanted limits in the proof but you could use them here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a \ne 0$.

Case 1: $f$ has only one real zero $x_0$ . Then $f(x)=a(x-x_0)^2 $

Now show that $a+b>c$ implies $a >0$. Hence $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

Case 2: $f(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$. From $f(-1) >0$, we get $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

assuming $a\neq 0$

*Observation 1*. "does not have two distinct real roots", which means:

**Either** have only one real root. In that case $\Delta=0$.

**Or** have no real roots. In that case $\Delta<0$

Both cases implies $f$ is either always non-negative or always non-positive, i.e. $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or $f(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

*Observation 2*. $f(-1)=a-b+c>0$.

Hence combining observation 1 observation 2 makes sure that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.